# Lubuntu bootloader failed to install 16.10

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to load Lubuntu 16.10 on a laptop that I wiped the Windows Vista from and get the "Bootloader failed to install"  error.  the correct drive is /dev/sda.  /dev/sda1 is also offered and neither work.  Only option is to stop installation.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Sounds like you try to install in UEFI-mode and there is no EFI-System-Partition. Install in legacy-mode or convert drive to GPT first to install in UEFI-mode. If you install in UEFI-mode you have to create ESP, you can do during install when you choose option `Something else` after booting installer. In legacy mode install Grub to `sda`, in UEFI-mode Grub will be installed in ESP.  The easy way is to install in legacy-mode. How you boot the installer is how you install. To install in legacy-mode boot installer in legacy-mode.